# Dompdf table rendering error

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm integrating Dompdf in my website. When ever I'm trying to render the table with a long text in one of the cell, it giving an error in PDF layout.

> HTML

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;text-align:center">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Sub Category</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>This is a long cell. Its not breaking</td>
        <td>IR Camera</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>545</td>
        <td>8942</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

> PHP

```
<?php 
// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = file_get_contents('print-bill.php');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('bill.pdf');

?>
```

**GENERATED PDF LOOKS THIS**
[image]

One cell is hovering the other one. Sentence is not breaking. In HTML layout, it looks fine. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: While I cannot pinpoint an error that may lead to your solution (although I should point out that you have misspelled your portrait orientation keyword as "potrait" in your sample code above), the generated PDF output that you show above indicates that your text widths are either incorrect for your selected font, or are not being evaluated at all; or it is substituting Courier in place of your selected font (which is not shown).Without text width evaluation working correctly, you will not see any linebreaks triggered where needed.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. It would also help to know if the table represents the document in its entirety. Any styling on the document can significantly affect the resulting render.